# Django is not going to directed url

Tags: python, django, django-templates

im a beginner and am following a tutorial online. i tried to duplicate what the instructor on my how however its not working and i dont know why. if you guys could help that'd be really appreciated.

I run server and go to the homepage which in this case is just http://127.0.0.1:8000/

but then when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/signups, nothing seems to happen, it just continues to show the home page. No Errors show

here are my relevant files:

App Level--------

AppThree/forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from AppThree.models import User


# Create your models here.
class NewUserSignUp(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

AppThree/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 125)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=265)
```

AppThree/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from AppThree import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.NewUserSignUp, name='NewUserSignUp'),
]
```

AppThree/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from AppThree.forms import NewUserSignUp


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'AppThree/home.html')


def NewUserSignUp(request):
    form = NewUserSignUp()


    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserSignUp(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return home(request)
            print("Validation Success")
        else:
            print("Error")

    return render(request, 'AppThree/SignUp.html',{'form':form})
```

End app Level --------------

Project level ----------

ProThree/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from AppThree import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^signup/', include('AppThree.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

endproject level -------

templates level ----

templates/AppThree/home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Well you gott his far.</h1>
        <h2>step 2: create a signup page</h2>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

templates/AppThree/SignUp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SignUp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is your signup page</h1>

        <form method="POST">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: You are using the same name for the view and form class.

Comment: Also the URL is /signup/, not /signups.

Comment: in url for `home` page, you need to put a `$` for the end of the regex pattern. Otherwise, all urls will match that pattern.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made those corrections and it worked! I appreciate the help!